# Android GridView - notifyDataSetChanged not refreshing the GridView

Tags: android, gridview, refresh, android-gridview, baseadapter

I am writing an app that displays a grid of images stored on a local database using `GridView`. I implemented the `deleteSelectedImage` method triggered by a button which deletes a given image of the grid in the database. The deletion works, but I cannot get my `GridView` to refresh by itself... If I close the activity and then open it again, the changes are visible.

Here's my code :

The activity :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GalleryShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String DEBUG_TAG = "GalleryShowActivity";

    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private Cursor c;

    private ImageAdapter mBaseAdapter;
    private TextView selectedImageText;
    private GridView mGridView;

    // currently selected position in the grid
    private int mSelectedPos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_show);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        c = db.getCursorOnAllImages(this);
        mBaseAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, c, db);
        mSelectedPos = -1;

        selectedImageText = (TextView)             findViewById(R.id.selectedImageText);
        selectedImageText.setText("Selected image : NONE");

        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mBaseAdapter);
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "IMAGE CLICKED");

                // click selects an image (can be changed later)
                mSelectedPos = position;
                selectedImageText.setText("Selected image : " + (position + 1));
            }
        });
     }


    public void deleteSelectedImage(View view) {
        boolean exists = c.moveToPosition(mSelectedPos);
        if (exists) {
            boolean success = db.deletePointedPicture(c, this);
            if (success) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "DELETE SUCCESS");
                mBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // display a success message...
            }
        } else {
            // display an error...
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the `ImageAdapter` class :

```
package ch.epfl.sweng.project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;


class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private DatabaseHandler mHandler;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, DatabaseHandler handler) {
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int rowHeight = 200;
        int rowWidth = 300;

        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(rowWidth, rowHeight));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Bitmap bm = mHandler.getImageByIndex(mCursor, position);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

I also tried this :

```
mBaseAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, c, db);
mGridView.setAdapter(mBaseAdapter);
```

Instead of :

```
mBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But it did not work.

Comment: where are you calling `deleteSelectedImage` from? I don't see this nor the button you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing it wrong. Even after deletion data in cursor will be same. Data in cursor is only updated when onCreate() is again called. Either update the cursor on deleteSelectedImage method after deleting the data and then call notifyDataSetChanged or try to pass list instead of cursor in constructor and while deleting, delete data from list as well as database and then call notifyDataSetChanged.